# Sending Commands from service to activity that are in different process by createPendingResult

Tags: java, android

Am trying to send commands back from service to activity..
I created one activity and i called a service. Am implemented in onActivityResult() in activity class. But am Unable to get how to use createPendingResult() .. am i cal it in service or activity. I read in some links it should be called from activity.But am unable to get. Please can anybody help me find out this.

Can anybody give an example..Thank You

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult() is used only between two activity. Not in between activity and service if you want to send data from service to activity then call Service via Intent

```
Intent i=new Intent(Service.this,youractivity.class);
i.putExtra(put your data here)
i.setFlag(Intent.Flag_New_task)// set flag newtask flag
Startactivity(i);
```

or Bind YourService check belowlink

service Binder:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

and
AIDL
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Thsts it...

Comment: ok..But i want know how to use createPendingResult() between service and activity..